# Nginx [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here

Tags: nginx

I'm coming with problem with NGinx - probably it's my fault somewhere but I can't find solution.

I made custom vhost block in DEFAULT nginx config. And I don't know if it's problem of that and I should do custom vhost in other file in "sites-available" or it's possible in this nginx config.

I'm struggling with that error:

> [root@openvpn etc]# nginx -t
>
> nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:69
>
> nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Here it's my `nginx.conf`

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;


    index index.php index.html;

    # Default server block
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  1.2.3.4;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        # Wordpress server
        server {
                server_name www.tested-dev.tk tested-dev.tk;
                access_log logs/tested-dev.access.log main;

                root /var/www/tested-dev.tk/;

                location / {
                        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                }
                        error_page 404 /404.html;
                        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
                        location = /50x.html {
                        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                }
                location ~ \.php$ {
                        try_files $uri =404;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Someone maybe have idea how to resolve that problem with second block (without giving it to second conf file)? And how I can optimize blocks?

Oh I should say why I won't "second block conf file".
Because on centos and in internet I can't find default site block file to copy to `sites-available` because every time when I'm starting configurating with

```
 server {
 ...
 }
```

I'm getting same thing about "server" directive is not allowed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "wordpress" server block is nested within the default server block, but it should be at the same level.

This is what you have:

```
server {
    ...
    server {
        # Your WordPress config
        ...
    }
}
```

Should be this way instead:

```
server {
    ...
}

server {
    # Your WordPress config
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you lookup at #Edit?

Comment: That should a separate question as it is quite unrelated to the original problem

Comment: Oh, ok - I will do it